# where to start on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie to Rails . So my question is from where should I get start for Rails.Is there any site or books for that.Ya I have read the documentation on rubyonrails.org.I want some  beginner  projects reference.where I can get some ideas about Rails.Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend watching Ryan Bates' brilliant `Railscasts` — http://railscasts.com/ .
Ryan has a unique talent of explaining even complex circumstances in a simple fashion and eliminating elements especially beginners won't have to worry about too much anyways.

*And just as a reminder: Don't forget that Rails is just a framework build on top of Ruby. You'll have to brush up on your Ruby skills, otherwise you won't get far with Rails either.*

Answer (score 1):

Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial is a great place to start:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

The book is available for free online, or you can pay for a PDF. He also has several free screencasts, and additional screencasts that you can pay for.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend http://guides.rubyonrails.com and book [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Good start for newbies is [Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), it's really useful,  because everything you've learned from this is using in the project. But i prefer [Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-on-Rails-3-tutorials/essential-training/55960-2.html), it's fast and significant course.

Answer (score 0):

I liked Head First Rails, it's using old rails, but its very simple

Answer (score 0):

A really good tutorial / basic starting point is [Rails for Zombies](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies).

It contains videos, screen casts and coding tests / challenges. It's fairly basic but very good for beginners.

An interactive tutorial for rails online!

The course is on code school, which has just started charging for new courses, but this one is free (and you don't need to enter cc etc to get it).